# Apache Nutch REST api

Tags: api, rest, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to launch a crawl via the rest api. A crawl starts with injecting urls. Using a chrome developer tool "Advanced Rest Client" I'm trying to build this POST payload up but the response I get is a 400 Bad Request.

POST - `http://localhost:8081/job/create`

Payload

```
{
  "crawl-id":"crawl-01",
  "type":"INJECT",
  "config-id":"default",
  "args":{ "path/to/seedlist/directory"}
}
```

My problem is in the args, I think more is needed but I'm not sure. In the NutchRESTAPI page this is the sample it gives for creating a job.

```
POST /job/create
   {
      "crawlId":"crawl-01",
      "type":"FETCH",
      "confId":"default",
      "args":{"someParam":"someValue"}
   }

POST /job/create
   {
      "crawlId":"crawl-01",
      "jobClassName":"org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob"
      "confId":"default",
      "args":{"someParam":"someValue"}
   }
```

I'm not sure what param or value to give each of the commands to complete a job. (eg. Inject, Generate, Fetch, Parse, and UpdateDb) Can someone clear this up? How do I tell the api where to look for the seedlist at?

**UPDATE**

When trying to complete the Generate command I came into a classException error where the value for the topN key is to be of type long but the api reads it as either a string or an int. I found a fix that is supposed to included in the 2.3.1 release (release date: TBA) and applied it and recompiled my code. It can now work.

Comment: Are you using Nutch 2.3?

Comment: Yes, I am. Just haven't found a full document listing all the possible arguments or values acceptable to make a proper crawl.

Comment: My answer below links to a more detailed document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this posting, the REST API is not yet complete. A much more detailed document exists, though it's still not comprehensive. It is linked to in the following email from the user mailing list (which you might want to consider joining):

http://www.mail-archive.com/user%40nutch.apache.org/msg13652.html

But to answer your question about the seedlist, you can create the seedlist through REST, or you can use the argument "seedDir"

```
{
    "args":{
        "seedDir":"/path/to/seed/directory"
    },
    "confId":"default",
    "crawlId":"sample-crawl-01",
    "type":"INJECT"
}
```

Comment: Using your answer seems to give me a 200 OK http response however the REST api is supposed return a job id if successful. Instead I get a response of `"Unexpected token c"`. My suspicions tell me it's because my path is a C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\folder. Is there something else I need to do to take care of this error?

Comment: Are you able to use that same path when you inject using the command line? (not using REST)

Comment: Have you tried replacing backslashes with forward slashes?

Comment: Yes, it works via command line. I'm using Advanced Rest Client chrome app to test these commands. The response was in JSON format which gave me the `Unexpected token c` output. When i switched to Raw it gave me the job id. I then checked the job by sending a GET request to localhost:8081/job and it said successful so I guess that worked!!! Now if I can only find examples of each job (INJECT, GENERATE, FETCH, PARSE, UPDATEDB) then I'd be set! Generate is currently failing due to my topN argument being an integer and not a long. Darn documentation, or lack of thereof.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it to work. As for the generate job, search the user mailing list archives: http://www.mail-archive.com/user%40nutch.apache.org/. There's a patch for the topN argument bug. Also, did the link in my answer work? There are examples for each job in the document.

Comment: Yes your link worked but I didn't see examples of each job there. Mainly saw about the Generate problem and then someone posted about the argument types available. Also, thank you for your help! But one last question. How would I apply this patch? I have the 2.3 precompiled version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81194/discussion-between-itsnino91-and-jgloves).